# How to show form errors on the same page and keep the data the user entered?

Tags: php, html

I have a form that has `action="file.php"` , That PHP file has the cheeks and outputs , I want these outputs to be on the same form page.

The form exists in an html file :

```
 <form class="" method="post" action="file.php">
    <!-- Some Form Fields -->
</form>
```

The file.php contains some checks and outputs like:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    if ( empty($name){
        echo "Name can't be empty.";
    }
}
```

How to show these outputs on the same page next to the form?

Comment: You have to either use javascript to validate the form before sending it or ajax

Comment: Use the `required` attribute in the form field and the browser will do it automatically.

Comment: @Barmar , But if the user removed these attributes , Then he can bypass it

Comment: If you wanna do it with PHP, you have to use ajax, there's no other way.

Comment: Is your form also on file.php? or you are posting to different page?

Comment: Hi Frank, do you simply want to return the posted variable with an error and show it on that respective page? We need a little more information before we can help you. I believe your question is about returning the validation errors and if there are none, simply the input as the output. Am I right?

Comment: @Frank The user can bypass anything you do client-side. You still have to check on the server.

Comment: @Andrew , No the form is on html file

Answer (score 1):

If you are posting to the same page, you can echo errors on the same page & retain the posted data no problem with something like this.

in php

```
   $errors = []
   if (empty($name){
        $errors['name'] = "Name can't be empty.";
    }
```

... and on the form

```
<php if (isset($errors['name'])) echo $errors['name']; ?>

<input name='name' value="<?php if (isset($_POST['name'])) echo $_POST['name']; ?>"></input>
```

If you are posting to a different url, then you will have to redirect back to the form page or include the form page, and pass the $errors and the $_POST data.

Answer (score 0):

Do everything in the same file.php:

```
<form class="" method="post" action="file.php">
    <!-- Some Form Fields -->
</form>
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    if ( empty($name){
        echo "Name can't be empty.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to have that validation in the same form file, let's call it '`form.html`', first rename it to '`form.php`'. Then add the `<?php ?>` tags above all the html code, and write your code there.

For that to work, you need to have to left empty the action attribute in form

```
   <?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        if ( empty($name){
            echo "Name can't be empty.";
        }
    }
    ?>
    <!-- Some HTML Code-->
    <form class="" method="post" action="">
        <!-- Some Form Fields -->
    </form>
```

I hope this answer your question about having the code in the same page, but if what you're trying to do is check if field is empty, i recommend you use the '`required`' attribute in the html form's input.